# Match dynamic keys during iteration

Tags: typescript

Consider the dynamic key defined in AttributableEntityData:

```
interface VendorAndVendorContacts {
    Vendor:AttributableEntityData,
    'Vendor Contact': Array<AttributableEntityData>
}

interface AttributableEntityData {
    [key: string] : {
        value: string;
        attributeId: number;
        attributeValueId?: number
    }
}

const vendorAndVendorContacts: VendorAndVendorContacts[] = [];
// build an array of objects, each object with a unique Vendor
exportFileData.map((efd: ExportFileData) => {
     if (vendorAndVendorContacts.filter((vvc: VendorAndVendorContacts) => vvc.Vendor['MATCH HERE!!'].value === getVendorName(efd)).length === 0) {
            vendorAndVendorContacts.push({
                Vendor: setVendorEntityData(efd, vendorColumnPrefix),
                'Vendor Contact': []
            });
        }
    });
```

What is the best way to match this value as seen in the map function?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that lets us see your issue when we paste it into our own IDEs.  Any private or third-party values or types should either be defined for us, or even better, removed and replaced with built-in things.  Right now my IDE doesn't know what to make of most of the stuff after `// build an array`.